# Outputting a set of graphics 3D objects with positions defined by one array and colors by another?

Tags: image-processing, graphics3d

I have a set of 2- or 3-space coordinates in an array, $(v_1,...,v_N)$, and an array of RGB color values (outputs from ImageValue[]) for each coordinate, $(c_1,...,c_N)$.  How can I output a graphics3D image where I have, say, spheres at each coordinate $v_i$ with an associated color $c_i$?

For an example with two coordinates, I might have a coordinate array {{0,10,0}, {20,30,0}} and a color array {{0.529412, 0.529412, 0.529412}, {0.647059, 0.647059, 0.647059}}.  I'd ideally like to be able to output two spheres are positions {{0,10,0}, {20,30,0}} in 3-space, where the first sphere has RGB value {0.529412, 0.529412, 0.529412} and the second sphere has RGB value {0.647059, 0.647059, 0.647059}.

Comment: Well, you didn't initially specify how your colors were formatted. I've now written an answer.

Comment: @J.M. Very good, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
Graphics3D[MapThread[{RGBColor @@ #1, Sphere[#2, 1]} &,
                     {{{0.529412, 0.529412, 0.529412}, {0.647059, 0.647059, 0.647059}},
                      {{0, 10, 0}, {20, 30, 0}}}], Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: some gray spheres]

But, if you can, why not stick to two dimensions?

```
Graphics[MapThread[{RGBColor @@ #1, Disk[Most[#2], 1]} &,
                   {{{0.529412, 0.529412, 0.529412}, {0.647059, 0.647059, 0.647059}},
                    {{0, 10, 0}, {20, 30, 0}}}]]
```

[image: and some gray disks]